# Why javascript shows 0 length for array with object property instead of indexed element

Tags: javascript

**For Example:**

```
var arr = [];
arr[3.4] = 1;
console.log(arr.length);
```

In the above code sample the `length` property holds zero why and what happened inside JS parser because it's length is zero.

Comment: Please look into this
[Length of a JavaScript object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An array's `length` is reflective of the *largest array index* present in the array. An "array index" (see below) is a property name that is an integer value less than 2<sup>32</sup>−1. Since `3.4` is not an integer, setting it does not alter the `length`.

Arrays are objects, so there is no reason why an array can't have a property named `3.4`, but that property doesn't influence the `length` because its name does not fit the criteria of an array index.

[ES2015 *9.4.2, Array Exotic Objects*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-array-exotic-objects) defines an "array index" as an integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>−1:

> A property name *P* (in the form of a String value) is an *array index* if and only if ToString(ToUint32(*P*)) is equal to P and ToUint32(*P*) is not equal to 2<sup>32</sup>−1."

And that definition is used in relation to the `length` value (emphasis mine):

> Every Array object has a `length` property whose value is always a nonnegative integer less than 2<sup>32</sup>. **The value of the `length` property is numerically greater than the name of every own property whose name is an *array index***; whenever an own property of an Array object is created or changed, other properties are adjusted as necessary to maintain this invariant. Specifically, **whenever an own property is added whose name is an array index, the value of the `length` property is changed**, if necessary, to be one more than the numeric value of that array index...

Comment: `length` reflects the largest array index, not the largest integer index. For example, `Object.assign([], {[1e53]:1}).length === 0`, but `Object.assign([], {[99]:1}).length === 100`

Comment: @Oriol Yes, I tried to make that clear in the second part of the answer, but I agree that the first sentence was inarguably incorrect. I wanted to communicate "if a key isn't an integer then it's ineligible to fit the definition of an array index" but I fell short of that. I hope my edit is better.

Answer (score 2):

A JavaScript array can not have fractional indexes.

What you have done there is assigned a property called `"3.4"` on the array object.

This does not affect the `length` property, which is designed to return one number higher than the highest valid index.

If you think about how arrays are supposed to work, you should realise a fractional offset doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using an object vs an array.

```
var arr = {};
arr[3.4] = 1;
arr[3.5] = 2;
arr[3.6] = 3;
console.log(Object.keys(arr).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use an integer as an index, not a float.

`var arr = [];
arr[3] = 1;
console.log(arr.length);`